# Inappbrowser closing with javascript on client side

Tags: android, cordova, inappbrowser

I am trying to display a webpages using in-app-browser in android platform of phone gap.
window.open() opening a url webpage which can call another html pages on to the server. I am trying to close the in-app-browser on any page (i.e., on very first loaded page or on intermediate page loaded or on the last page) by clicking a close hyperlink which calls a javascript function iabClose(event)
but the in-app-browser is not closing.

Please help me if anybody knows the solution or any other better way of closing in-app-browser.
Thanks in advance

Code:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
         var iabRef = null;

         function inApp() {
         iabRef = window.open('http://202.65.155.246/Real_Time_Data        /SSEClient.aspx', '_blank', 'location=no');
         iabRef.addEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
         iabRef.addEventListener('exit', iabClose); 
         }

         function iabLoadStop(event) {
         if(event.url == "http://202.65.155.246/Real_Time_Data/CloseIAB.aspx"){
         iabRef.close();
         }               
         }

         function iabClose(event) {
         iabRef.removeEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
         iabRef.removeEventListener('exit', iabClose);
         }      
      </script>        
      <title>Hello World</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <a href="#" onclick="inApp()" style="font-size:30px;">Click Here</a>  </br></br>      
      <a href="" onclick="iabExit()" style="font-size:30px;">Exit</a>   
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: add some console.log or alerts to check if the code is executing at all

Comment: wild guess `iabLoadStop` works once. AS  jcesarmobile said, add some console.log or alerts and see if code executes as you expected or not, where it gets stuck etc.